# Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js

I have problem including controller file in nodejs router file

my router file has

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express.Router();
var ctrl = require('../controller/designer.js');
var renderpages = require('../controller/renderingpages.js')
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

In designer.js file i have a following structure

```
var ctrl = 
{

  //controller code
}
module.exports = ctrl
```

in renderingpages.js file i have a following structure

```
var renderpages = 
{
  //controller code
}
module.exports = renderpages
```

i have this issue after including renderingpages.js

Comment: See my answer. But to add on to it. Do you have any examples of the get routes you are using in `renderingpages`?

Comment: I think it will be a route that relies on the `ctrl` or `renderpages` controllers causing the issue

Comment: if i not include the renderingpages.js file it will working fine

Comment: i don't know why they give negative marks , i questioned correctly i think .. now i fix the issue as @Treeless said .. thanks every one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error: Route.get() refers to some line of code that is a get request.

The error means that when your making your get request you are passing an object rather then the expected callback function needed by the request.

What it should look like:

```
//Format should be '/route', callback
app.get('/iamroute', function(req, res) {
   //callback
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`exports._function_name = () => {}`

```js
// In designer.js file, change into the following structure

exports.ctrl = (req, res, next) =>{
  //controller code
  console.log('running ctrl')
  next()
}


// in renderingpages.js file, change into the following structure


exports.renderpages = (req, res, next) =>{
  //controller code
  console.log('running renderpages')
  next()
}
```

rather than directly sending an object in form of module.exports = {
someFunction,
someObject
}