# Error connection MongoDB: Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to connect my application to `MongoDB` using `express` but without success. Below the most important part of the code:

**app.js**:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const vesselController = require('./controllers/VesselController');
require('./config/keys');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;

const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    poolSize: 10
};

mongoose
    .connect(db, options)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connection established'))
    .catch((err) => console.log('Error connecting MongoDB database due to: ', err));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(cors());

app.route('/vessels/all').get(vesselController.getBaseAll);
app.route('vessels/:id/track').get(vesselController.getCurrent);
app.route('/vessels').get(vesselController.getHistory);

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

**VesselController.js**

```
const Vessels = require('../models/Vessels');
const Positions = require('../models/Positions');
const Compnanies = require('../models/Companies');

exports.getBaseAll = (req, res) => {
    Promise.all([
        Compnanies.find(),
        Vessels.find(),
        Positions.aggregate([
            {
                $sort: {
                    date: -1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$callsign',
                    details: {
                        $push: '$$ROOT'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: {
                    newRoot: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [ '$details', 0 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
    ])
        .then(([ companies, vessels, positions ]) => {
            // apply vessels detail table as join:
            positions.forEach((pos) => {
                vessels.forEach((ves) => {
                    if (pos.callsign == ves.callsign) {
                        p._detail = ves;
                    }
                });
                companies.forEach((com) => {
                    if (p._detail.company == com.number) {
                        p._detail = com;
                    }
                });
            });
            res.status(200).json(positions);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        });
};

exports.getHistory = (req, res) => {
    var id = req.param.id;
    Positions.find(
        {
            callsign: id,
            date: {
                $gte: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
            }
        },
        (err, task) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).json(task);
        }
    );
};

exports.getCurrent = (req, res) => {
    var currentPos = Positions.find({
        date: {
            $gte: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60)
        }
    });
    currentPos.exec((err, task) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.status(200).json(task);
    });
};
```

I am not sure if the problem is due to the fact that I am trying to connect to a specific database. After hitting **connect** to my application as shown below and copy/paste the key:

[image: connection]

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@vessel-tracker-cluster-x2lpw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Below is how my cluser is organized:

[image: cluster]

And after accessing the collections you can see how the database is structured:

[image: db]

**What I have done** to solve the problem:

Posts that I came across and analyzed to solve the problem were:

1) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object) was useful but I could not solve the problem.

2) I used [this other source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216932/error-route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined) but problem still stays.

3) [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775212/nodejs-route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-string) was also useful but my problem still stay and `MongoDB` is not properly connecting

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Probably there's something about vesselController. Could you please add its code?

Comment: @HlibDerbenov, thanks for reading the question. I just updated the question with `VesselController.js` file

Comment: Thank you. Do you have access to terminal where the error "Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]" appears? There should be a stack trace with the exact line of code which generates this error.

Comment: Sure, Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/JPUOje0.png) useful?

Comment: Yes, could you please have a look at my answer?

Comment: I am reading it now and try what you are suggesting. Give me a little bit to try the solution and will get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see from the stack trace there's an error in app.js:77:27:

> app.route('/vessels/all').get(vesselController.getBaseAll);

Though I've executed your code and it worked fine I would like to propose you the following:

1) Try to substitute `exports` with `module.exports` in your VesselController.js;

2) Try to debug app.js and see what `vesselController.getBaseAll` / `vesselController.getCurrent` / `vesselController.getHistory` returns:

> console.log(vesselController.getBaseAll); // should be [Function]

Comment: Thanks, I had to switch `exports` with `module.exports` as you proposed. However could you please explain the difference? Thanks :)

Comment: @Emanuele "exports is shortcut for referencing module.exports, if your module is to export an object. It is a pretty much usless object if your module exports any other data type or you have assigned anything to module.exports." https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/exports-vs-module-exports.html